# Add Quantity to Existing Item on DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I'm working on a POS system , and my problem is when I add a existing item on the data grid, it will just add the same item for example

This is the Information of the Product :

[image: Item Info]

The output when I click ok :

[image: Output]
This my codes for Adding :

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now.Date;

        if (Buy.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity required", "ADD", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        else
        {

            try
            {

                conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("select PurchaseNo from Purchase where CustomerNO = '" + CustomerID.Text + "'", conn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    label18.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                }
                if (label18.Text == OR.Text)
                {

                    conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Purchase where PurchaseNo ='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value + "'And CustomerNO ='" + CustomerID.Text + "'", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                    label18.ResetText();

                }
                dr.Dispose();
                int t = 0;

                conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
                conn.Open();

                string fullname = fName.Text + " " + lName.Text;

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Purchase(PurchaseNo, CustomerNO,StaffID) values ('"
                    + OR.Text + "','"
                    + CustomerID.Text + "','"
                    + txtStaffID.Text + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Details(PurchaseNo, ProductID, Quantity, Price, Subtotal) values ('"
                    + OR.Text + "','"
                    + itemID.Text + "','"
                    + Buy.Text + "','"
                    + Price.Text + "','"
                    + Subtotal.Text + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Item Added");
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select Qty from Product where ProductID ='" + itemID.Text + "'", conn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    t = Convert.ToInt32(itemQty.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(Buy.Text);

                }
                dr.Dispose();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Product set Qty ='" + t + "' where ProductID ='" + itemID.Text + "'", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dr.Dispose();

                conn = koneksyon.getConnect();
                conn.Open();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Visible = true;


                //cmd = new SqlCommand("Select a.ProductID, a.Description, a.Qty, b.Price, b.SupplierID from Product as a inner join Inventory as b on a.ProductID = b.ProductID", con);


                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select b.ProductID,c.Description, b.Quantity,b.Price, b.Subtotal , a.CustomerNO, b.PurchaseNo from Details as b inner join Purchase as a  on b.PurchaseNo= a.PurchaseNo join Product c on c.ProductID = b.ProductID where CustomerNO ='" + CustomerID.Text + "'", conn);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5], dr[6]);
                }
                dr.Dispose();

                //cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Purchase Set PurchaseNo ='" + OR.Text + "', CustomerNO ='" + CustomerID.Text + "'", conn);
                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                itemID.Clear();
                Price.Clear();
                itemDesc.Clear();
                itemQty.Clear();
                Subtotal.Clear();
                Buy.Enabled = false;
                Buy.Clear();
                itemCode.Clear();
                itemCode.Focus();
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }

    }
```

Now my Problem is when I add another the same Item it will show like this :

[image: Another Item when add]

, I want to display it Like this , but I dont know how to do it :

[image]

Comment: check 1st if data already exist in your grid like using id or anythings else that can track that the same item. Use loop on it, before you insert it into the grid. like for each row etc. then compare the id of existing item in your grid to the new item if id are equals then increment/add the quantity to the txtquantity else proceed to the next loop. and so on

Comment: i have an answer but in vb.net and also i cannot follow your code :D so i will give you a suggestions or trick. Maybe you can use it